tensorflow and keras not using mac M2 ultra GPU
I am trying tensorflow and keras in R, I followed the instruction of the installation in this link:
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/
and
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/local_gpu
When I tried the test:
library(tensorflow)
tf$config$list_physical_devices("GPU")

it returns:
list()

Which means that the TensorFlow is not using a GPU
Then I tried the following code:
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
train_images <- mnist$train$x
train_labels <- mnist$train$y
test_images <- mnist$test$x
test_labels <- mnist$test$y
model <- keras_model_sequential(list(
layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu"),
layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "softmax")
))

2024-04-09 11:48:51.673016: I metal_plugin/src/device/metal_device.cc:1154] Metal device set to: Apple M2 Ultra
2024-04-09 11:48:51.673043: I metal_plugin/src/device/metal_device.cc:296] systemMemory: 192.00 GB
2024-04-09 11:48:51.673051: I metal_plugin/src/device/metal_device.cc:313] maxCacheSize: 72.00 GB
2024-04-09 11:48:51.673095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:306] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2024-04-09 11:48:51.673134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:272] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)

and the model is not build
Please help

You can see in the messages that the M2 Ultra GPU is detected, we have no idea what you mean by "model is not build".

The 'tensorflow-metal' package has not been updated yet for Keras3+Tensorflow v2.16.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/63854
